# How to create an event only once when a date is reached?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, scheduled-tasks, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Let's say I can schedule a thing in the future (a show for example) in the future.

I want for example to emit an event "10 days" before the scheduled date.
or
I want to emit an event "3 days" after the scheduled date (the show happened).

I've stored in my DB the scheduled date.

What would be the best approach, from an architectural point of view, to do this?

I've think about doing regular polling of my DB to fetch matching date but i'm afraid to face several issues such as:

- How to avoid generating multiple events once the date is reached (NOW() + 10 days > scheduled date)
- How to avoid missing events (let's say I use a cron every minute and constraint the range to a minute, I may miss events).

I'm looking for enterprise pattern and I'm pretty sure it exists kind of strategies to manage this use case in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the emission of events is a domain concern.  It is not simply an infrastructure requirement to satisfy a technical requirement (e.g. propagation of data between domains).  Therefore, I would agree that the business logic is not something you should delegate to RabbitMQ.

Given this, I would build the event handling into domain logic.

**Show**

```
public class Show : EntityBase
{
    public DateTime ScheduledDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool PreShowNotificationSent { get; set; }
    public bool PostShowNotificationSent { get; set; }

    public void NotifyPre()
    {
        if (PreShowNotificationSent)
        {
            throw InvalidOperationException("Notification already sent");
        }
 
        base.AddDomainEvent(PreShowNotificationSentEvent(this));

        PreShowNotificationSent = true;
    }

    // repeat for NotifyPost()
}
```

Then initialise a background service at startup that will run based on your preferred schedule (e.g. every 1 minute).

That service will initiate a command handler (SendPreShowNotifications) every 1 minute.

That command handler will retrieve a "ShowNotifier" entity from your repository (this entity is the aggregate for handling notifications).  The repository will retrieve a ShowNotifier and child objects for all Shows that meet the notification criteria and have 'false' for the appropriate 'PreShowNotificationSent' or 'PostShowNotificationSent'.

**ShowNotifier**

```
public class ShowNotifier
{
    List<Show> ShowsNeedingPreNotification { get; set; }
    List<Show> ShowsNeedingPostNotification { get; set; }

    public void Notify()
    {
        foreach (Show show in ShowsNeedingPreNotification)
        {
            show.NotifyPre();
        }

        foreach (Show show in ShowsNeedingPostNotification)
        {
            show.NotifyPost();
        }
    }
}
```

**ShowNotifier Repository**

```
public async Task<ShowNotifier> GetWithPendingAsync()
{
    List<Show> pre = await _db.Shows.Where(s => 
        s.ScheduledDate is-within-10-days
        && s.PreShowNotificationSent == false).ToListAsync();

    List<Show> post = // similar to above for post notifications

    return new ShowNotifier()
    {
        ShowsNeedingPreNotification = pre;
        ShowsNeetingPostNotification = post;
    }
}
```

**Command Handler**

```
ShowNotifier notifier = await _showNotifierRepository.GetWithPendingAsync();

notifier.Notify();
```

**Domain Event Handler (for PreShowNotificationSentEvent)**

```
// Publish the integration event on the bus
await EventBus.PublishAsync(new ShowComingUpIntegrationEvent(
    domainEvent.Show.Name,
    domainEvent.Show.ScheduledDate));
```

Using the above approach will keep the core logic in your domain, whilst ensuring that only one event is sent for each Show.

Depending on your style, you could lift ShowNotifier out of your domain entities and make it a Domain Service that uses Show repositories to retrieve the Shows before calling NotifyPre or NotifyPost.

Answer (score 0):

You can also publish delayed messages(events) on the service bus. If you don't use a message bus system you can apply a cornjob system and keep track in the aggregate if events have been published.

Comment: what do you mean by "publish delayed messages"? I'm using a message bus but which use rabbitMQ as a transport (for async messages) but I can't rely on rabbitmq features

Comment: Some service bus application, like Azure service bus has the feature to delay messages. Thus the will be send to the broker, but the broker will queue the messages when the given time has been passed.